# How to convert a normal std::string to OssBitString?

Tags: c++, c++11, asn.1, bitstring

The OssBitString takes in string length (in bits) and a const unsigned char* as parameters. However, when I convert the input std::string to const unsigned char* and pass it to OssBitString, the contents of the string get modified and contains weird characters.The following is the conversion function from std::string to OssBitString:

```
inline const OssBitString converter(const std::string&s, int size)
{
   return(size, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(s.c_str()))
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed. I tried to convert the string into binary format and then convert as a OssBitString as well. But it did not work. How to convert std::string to OssBitString then?

Comment: It's difficult to answer this question without seeing the code. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you taking into account that the `length` is expressed in **bits** and not in **bytes**? `OssBitString` should not be modifying the `std::string` at all, unless you are doing something to corrupt memory, like with a buffer overflow.

Comment: The code looks like it won't compile. Apart from missing a trailing `;`, the expression following the `return` statement looks like it is missing a call to the `OssBitString` constructor. Are you intending to call https://www.oss.com/asn1/products/documentation/asn1_cpp_6.7/asn1cpp-runtime-representation-classes.html#OssBitString_length_char ? As @RemyLebeau points out, the length is in *bits*. And what are you passing in to `converter` as the size parameter? Shouldn't you pass `s.size()*8` instead?